# Proper response returned from Spring controller but control goes to Ajax error 406 : Not Acceptable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

My ajax call looks like this,

```
function getInfo(pNum){
        //AJAX Start            
        $.ajax({  
         type: "GET", 
               contentType : "application/json",
         url: "getPInfo.do",  
         data: "&pNum=" + pNum,
         dataType : 'json',
         async: false,
        success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        if(response !== null || response !== ''){   
                        var JSONresponse = JSON.parse(response);
                        var a = JSONresponse.status;    
                        alert(a);
                 }},  
                 error: function(e){                    
                    alert("Error..."+e);
                 } 
        });


    }
```

Controller code as follows

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPInfo.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody JsonResponse getPInfo(@RequestParam("pNum") Long pNum, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request ) { 
        JsonResponse  result = new JsonResponse();

        try {

                Perm  perm = new Perm();
                perm = pService.getPInfo(pNum);

                if(perm != null){
                    result.setStatus("SUCCESS");                    
                    result.setResult(perm);
                }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception ", e);
        }  

        return result;

    }
```

This is my JsonResponse class.

```
public class JsonResponse {

    private String status = null;  
    private Object result = null;


    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Object getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(Object result) {
        this.result = result;
    }   


}
```

When i try to print perm all the objects are set properly. But ajax return goes to 
 error: function(e) .

Comment: what does `alert(response) ` print?

Comment: @ktilcu - return doesnt goto success loop, i see the alert inside error :function [Object Object]

Comment: Use `alert('Error...' + JSON.stringify(e))` to clear up the `[Object Object]`

Comment: We should definitely see the error details as @ktilcu suggests in order to inspect further. But I think you should also try to remove `HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request` parameters from your controller to perform a check. In some spring versions, this can cause trouble sometimes.

Comment: I am getting 406 Not Acceptable. I have jackson-annotations-2.7.5.jar, jackson-core-2.7.5.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.jar in my classpath and EAR lib though. Still the issue exists

Comment: Try to you add to your RequestMapping:
 `produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}`

Comment: @ T A - tried but didnt work same issue.

Comment: if it's a 400 level error then you should make sure your API is working. I don't know spring but i would test with curl.

Comment: @ktilcu  its 406 not acceptable

Comment: check your API with curl. If it works post the output. The 406 means that the request isn't being processed by the API correctly.